# Ionic/Cordova does not update versionCode for Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, configuration, version

When I change the `version` in my `config.xml`, the internal Android `versionCode` ist not updated to the new value. Android Console is always showing an error because "I already have an App with that versionCode on the Play Store".

I've also tried the following things in `config.xml`

```
<widget ... version="1.1.4" versionCode="10104" android-versionCode="10104" ...>
<platform name="android">
  <preference name="android-manifest/@android:versionCode" value="114" />
</platform>
```

Doesn't work. The `versionCode` stays the same.

**UDPATE**: I deleted the Android platform and re-added it, now it works!

Answer (score 2):

Changing VersionCode manually is not a good idea , You should only change 
version in config.xml,after that run

```
ionic build --release android
```

It will automatically update your AndroidManifest.xml.Make sure if version code is updated before publishing your app to play store.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I've done exactly that, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I find that when you run run android ionic or ionic build android generates the version of the code in the same as the version, is not a good practice to change this code, but if you want to change: you must change only the `proyect/platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml,`

I let you link that may interest you. 
[Here!](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-site/issues/264)

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the AndroidManifest.xml, but that didn't changed anything.